# MongoDB nested Array find and projection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I'm currently working with **mongodb** (*mongoose*). One of my example documents is:

```
myuser{
  _id: 7777...,
  money: 1000,
  ships:[{
    _id: 7777...
    name: "myshipname",
    products:[{
      product_id: 7777....,
      quantity: 24
    }]
  }
}
```

What I aim to do is to get a certain **product** given user id, ship id and product id, being the result something like: `{ product_id: 777..,quantity:24}`

So far I got to find a certain user ship with:

```
findOne(userId,ships:{ $elemMatch: {_id:shipId}})
```

Which returns the information of the ship with shipId inside the array *ships* from user with userId. However, I cannot find the way to get only a certain product from that ship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can probably best be done using the aggregation framework. Something like:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: { _id : <user>}},
  {$unwind: "$ships"},
  {$unwind: "$ships.products"},
  {$match: { "ships._id": <ship>}},
  {$match: { "ships.products.product_id": <product>}}
]);
```

Note I'm not on a computer with mongo right now, so my syntax might be a bit off.